# Como generar un loop para generar informes en Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr, r-markdown

Tengo un archivo .rmd en donde tengo todo lo necesario para generar mi pdf en `Rmarkdown`, pero el problema es que cada vez que quiero cambiar una variable, lo hago en el `chunk` y luego aprieto `knit`, esto no seria problema si tuviera que hacer pocos informes, pero tengo aproximadamente que hacer 1000 de ellos.

Para cambiar el nombre de archivo de salida de mi pdf tengo esto

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_file = file.path(dirname(inputFile), 'Canton1.pdf')) })
output: 
  pdf_document
```

Y en mi primer `Chunk` tengo mi variable para cambiar y un enlace para agregar una imagen con dicha variable. Pongo un ej : Si quiero hacer el informe para la variable 1, cargo la imagen 1.

```
n_canton = 1
include_graphics("F:/Imagenes_canton/canton001.png")  ## Inserto la imagen correspondiente al canton
```

Seria interesante generar algun tipo de loop para que me facilite el trabajo, necesito algo asi :

Para el canton 1 hasta el n, que se me generaran los pdf correspondiente.
Leyendo un poco sobre esto, me genere otro script aparte, pero no logro con la solucion ya que me genera error en pdf, algo raro si con `knit` funciona. Es este

```
library(rmarkdown)

n_canton = c(1:5)  ## Esto lo puse para generar 5 de prueba 

for(i in 1:length(n_canton)){
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = "Apeo_C.Real_markdown.Rmd",
    output_file = str_glue("F://Report_{n_canton[i]}.pdf"),
    params = list(n_canton  = n_canton[i]))
}
```

En resumen:
Necesito facilitarme el trabajo al generar tantos informes, actualmente cambio el `rmd` en 3 posiciones

1. En el nombre de salida del pdf
2. En la variable
3. En la imagen a cargar.

Si a alguno se le ocurre una idea en donde cambie el número de variable y a su vez carga esa imagen que le corresponde estaría super agradecido.

Un saludo a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos lo básico para lograr lo que buscas

#### En el `archivo.Rmd`

1. Hay que modificar el header `yaml` para agregar las variables que te interesan manejar desde afuera de `knit`, por ejemplo:

   ```
   params:
     cantidad: 10
     imagen: NULL
   ```

   En este ejemplo vamos a manejar una variable `cantidad` inicializada en 10 e `imagen` para indicar la imagen a incluir. Conviene inicializar estas variables con valores válidos de prueba, así también nos funciona el clásico botón `knitr`.
2. Usar estas variables dentro del código markdown mediante el objeto `parms`, por ejemplo:

   a. En un `chunk` que hace una gráfica

   ```
   plot(runif(params$cantidad))
   ```

   b. En un código "inline"

   ```
   Este markkdown tiene un parámetro `cantidad` cuyo valor ahora es `r params$cantidad`
   ```

   c. Para incluir una imagen

   ```
   La imagen:

   `r sprintf("![Una imagen externa](%s)",params$imagen)`
   ```

#### En el código `R` que va a renderizar los `PDF`

De alguna manera tenemos que configurar las variables a pasar a `knit` y luego, como ya lo has intentado, iterar y usar `rmarkdown::render`, el archivo a generar es sencillo de definir, lo único que restaría es pasar las variables a `render()`, para lo cual se usa el parámetro `params`

```
parametros = data.frame(cantidad=c(10, 1000),
                        imagen=c("imagen_001.jpg",
                                 "imagen_002.jpg"))

for(row in 1:nrow(parametros)){
  print("Render:")
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = "Prueba.Rmd",
    output_file = paste0("Report_", parametros$cantidad[row], ".pdf"),
    params = list(cantidad = parametros$cantidad[row],
                  imagen = parametros$imagen[row])
  )
}
```

Este ejemplo, por comodidad definí un `data.frame` con una columna para `cantidad` y otra para `imagen`, esto ciertamente podría configurarse desde un archivo externo tipo `csv` o `Excel`. Definimos 2 generaciones de `pdf`, con dos imágenes a incluir distintas y 2 parámetros de cantidad, que además usamos para definir el nombre del archivo y el `plot`.

El código completo `rmarkdown` del ejemplo, sería algo así:

````
---
title: "Prueba"
author: "Nombre del autor"
date: "2/7/2021"
output: pdf_document
params:
  cantidad: 10
  imagen: NULL
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Ejemplo de Markdown parametrizables

Este markkdown tiene un parámetro `cantidad` cuyo valor ahora es `r params$cantidad` y este gráfico se genera en función de dicho valor.

```{r echo=FALSE}
plot(runif(params$cantidad))
```

La imagen:

`r sprintf("![Una imagen externa](%s)",params$imagen)`
````

Si lo guardas en una carpeta, junto con el código `R` que hace el render de los PDF´s y copias dos imágenes cualquiera con los nombres `imagen_001.jpg` e `imagen_002.jpg`, además de setear el "working directory" a esta misma carpeta con `setwd()`, y ejecutas el código `R` deberías obtener dos archivos `pdf` parecidos pero distintos.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMorancho que tal? Muchas gracias por el detalle de tu respuesta, hice tal cual lo que me comentas pero me da un fallo de ! LaTeX Error: Environment tabu undefined. Lo raro es que si hago el Knit a pdf, lo hace sin problemas, es cuando hago el render desde el script de R. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Fijate si esto: https://community.rstudio.com/t/render-rmd-from-rscript-does-not-work/3998/6 te da una pista.

Comment: lo pude resolver al final, te agradezco la ayuda. Un Saludo!